# How do i do an script to go to the previous and the forward page?

Tags: jquery

I'm programming in PHP, but i'm very noob at JQuery.

I'm doing pagination, and i already have the pages working.

I would like to build an script to go back and forward, adding more 1 to the page variable everytime that a button is clicked.

```
<button type="button" class="class">Next</button>

$('.class').click(function() {
var page = 1;
page++;
window.location.href = '/admin/module/page/' + page;
});
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: This code only works one time, i would like to sum more 1 number everytime that the button is clicked

Comment: That code should work if it is posted in each page and the jQuery library is included in each. Any errors in the console when you get to the second page? Are you setting the page variable properly each time, or is it always 1?

Comment: no, i'm not getting any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the number page from PHP. You can put it in a input hidden :

```
<input type="hidden" id="page_number" value="<?php echo $page_number;?>" />
```

and from your Javascript code you can do :

```
$('.class').click(function() {
    var page = document.getElementById("page_number").value;
    page++;
    window.location.href = '/admin/module/page/' + page;
});
```

But I'm not sure that I understand your problem.

Comment: I would suggest to simply generate it into the javascript, instead of wrapping it in a `input`.

Comment: Yes but if he want to put the javascript in a file he can't put the page_number in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The `page` variable is reset every time the page is reloaded.

I suggest to generate the `page` variable from PHP. It knows there way the page is, so just set it there.

```
<button type="button" class="class">Next</button>

$('.class').click(function() {
  window.location.href = '/admin/module/page/<?php echo $page_next ?>';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `var page = 1;` outside of the click function otherwise it will reset to `1` each them you click on the `.class` element or the page reloads

```
var page = 1; 
  // instead of this I would recommend you get the current page from the url
  // something like var page = window.location.href.split('/page/')[1];
  // of course also check if it exists else it's `2`

$('.class').click(function () {
    page = page + 1;
    window.location.href = '/admin/module/page/' + page;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to get pagenum from url, no PHP required:

```
var url = document.URL;
var pageNum = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var page = (pageNum == '') ? 2 : (parseInt(pageNum) + 1);

$('.class').click(function() {
    window.location.href = '/admin/module/page/' + page;
});
```